# Boot Animation Will Not Loop

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, boot-animation

Samsung Fascinate running CyanogenMod 10.1-20130723-Nightly.

I made a custom boot animation that works, but it plays once and does not loop. The `desc.txt` file has the **proper formatting to loop**, folder structure and zip method. I have the *bootanimation.zip* in two locations on the device memory: `/system/media` and `/data/local`

I have matched the permissions to the other files on both locations, however that still hasn't fixed it. Why is not looping like it's supposed to? When I restore the CyanogenMod animation it plays just fine.

UPDATE: Downloading boot animations from the [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2334927) worked just fine. I tried three. Mine are still refusing to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out after troubleshooting.

I partitioned out my HDD and installed Ubuntu 13.04. Once completed I installed Android Tools via terminal `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`

I recreated the entire boot animation using Gimp and 7Zip and pushed it back to the device `adb push /system/media/bootanimation.zip`. It worked. For what ever reason creating it in Windows was not working.

Answer (score 5):

Create an animation script (text) file as `desc.txt` with the following content:

```
240 320 24  
p 1 0 part0
```

Explanation:

1. In first line `240 320 24`, `240` `320` is the device's resolution and `24` is the frames per second. Higher the number, faster the animation.
2. In second line `p 1 0 part0`, `p` is a code to tell it to look at new commands, `1` is the number of times the boot animation will play (`0` means infinite), `0` is a code to tell it to pause. 0 means no pause, 10 means pause for 10 seconds - repeating or moving on to next line.
   `part0` is the foler in which your animation images are contained.

Could you please check whether fourth parameter is `0`? If not set it to `0` for infinite loop.

Comment: I have no part 1. I just have a simple animation that loops and needs to be repeated. 

This is what my txt file looks like:

480 480 24
p 0 0 part0

Comment: try to give looping count to 5 or 6 instead of 0. Please let me know the result

Comment: Didn't display at all. I did both power off and reboot.

Comment: I created a part zero and one. Part zero fades in and part 1 is supposed to loop. It doesn't. Part zero fades and stops. No animation.